# Как заставить EditText не увеличиваться с добавлением в него нового текста?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как заставить `EditText` не увеличиваться с добавлением в него нового текста? Т.е. при добавлении нового текста, о не должен показывать его полностью и расширяться,а лишь то,что влазит в его рамки? Какой атрибут отвечает за это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно выставить количество линий текста

- через xml: maxLines или lines
- через код: setMaxLines(int linesCount);

Comment: А ещё в xml можно выставить `android:singeLine="true"`